# Access Sibling elements in Angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to show an 'hr' divider when it has previous and next siblings in below html content:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-if="condition1">One</li>
    <li ng-if="condition2">Two</li>
    <divider>
    <li ng-if="condition3">Three</li>
    <li ng-if="condition4">Four</li>
</ul>
```

The `divider` directive definition is as below:

```
restrict: 'EA'
transclude: true
priority: -1
scope: {}
template: '<hr ng-if="show">'
link:
    post:(scope, element, attrs) ->
      // check if divider element has previous and next siblings here; How to do it??
      scope.show = true
```

I am not sure how to access the sibling elements. I tried element.sibling(), element.next().

When I used element.parent().html() in console, it shows:

```
<!-- ngIf: condition1 -->
<!-- ngIf: condition2 -->
<divider><hr ng-if="show"></divider>
<!-- ngIf: condition3 -->
<!-- ngIf: condition4 -->
```

The ng-if conditions above are not evaluated before  though the priority has been set to '-1'.

Can you please help.

Comment: This might be a lot easier to accomplish with a single directive that just builds the html on the fly.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot do that because I have many such <ul> items with different contents in my app.

Comment: have another directive in the <ul> and have <divider> communicate with that parent directive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using CSS instead, it's simpler.

You can easily hide any divider that:

1. Is at the beginning of the list
2. Is at the end of the list
3. Is after another divider (prevents duplicate dividers)

Example:

```css
.divider:first-child,
.divider:last-child,
.divider + .divider { display: none; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="divider">-----</li>
  <li>One</li>
  <li class="divider">-----</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li class="divider">-----</li>
  <li class="divider">-----</li>
  <li class="divider">-----</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="divider">-----</li>
</ul>
```

This will render as expected

Comment: No problem, sometimes the best solution is to use a different tool :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use native JavaScript functions to check if previous and next siblings exist like this:

```
var prevNode = element[0].previousElementSibling;
var nextNode = element[0].nextElementSibling;

scope.show = prevNode && nextNode;
```

Optionally, you can check if previous and next nodes are `li` elements by modifying the last line in the above example as this:

```
scope.show = prevNode && nextNode && prevNode.nodeName === 'LI' && nextNode.nodeName === 'LI';
```

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sbHCMcOTkACOrAqSHS0s?p=preview) to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$imeout` to see the resolved conditions in the next digest cycle.

Once you do that you're able to go through the siblings and show it when there are visible elements before and after the directive:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.condition1 = true;
  $scope.condition2 = false;
  $scope.condition3 = false;
  $scope.condition4 = true;
});

app.directive('divider', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    priority: -1,
    scope: {},
    template: '<hr ng-if="show">',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {

        var myIndex, siblings = element.parent().children(),
          numSiblings = siblings.length;

        //find sibling position of this directive
        for (var i = 0; i < numSiblings; i++) {
          if (siblings[i] === element[0]) {
            myIndex = i;
            break;
          }
        }

        /* If myIndex is not 0 then there is an element before it.
           If myIndex is less than (numSibling - 1) then this is an element after it. */
        scope.show = (myIndex > 0 && myIndex < numSiblings - 1) ? true : false;
      }, 0);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <em>Example #1 - 1 (or more) elements before, 1 (or more) elements after:</em>
  <ul>
    <li ng-if="condition1">One</li>
    <li ng-if="condition2">Two</li>
    <divider></divider>
    <li ng-if="condition3">Three</li>
    <li ng-if="condition4">Four</li>
  </ul>
  <em>Example #2 - 0 elements before, 1 (or more) elements after:</em>
  <ul>
    <li ng-if="condition2">Two</li>
    <divider></divider>
    <li ng-if="condition3">Three</li>
    <li ng-if="condition4">Four</li>
  </ul>
  <em>Example #3 - 1 (or more) element before, 0 elements after:</em>
  <ul>
    <li ng-if="condition1">One</li>
    <li ng-if="condition2">Two</li>
    <divider></divider>
    <li ng-if="condition3">Three</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/S55WMP4dGzb2IP7JAnVP?p=preview

Comment: This may work. But I used css to control as suggested by @oodavid . Thanks for the answer